# What is TCP's three way handshake response to old connection?

Tags: tcp

Lets say we have two hosts (A and B). How does the three way handshake process prevent a old SYN-segment from A to connect to B. It starts with A sending a SYN to B, and then B responding with?

Comment: There is no concept of an "old" SYN.

Comment: It doesn't use NAK right? It responds with SYNACK then when A receives this response it will not complete the connection since it did not wish to establish this connection? At least that's what I have figured out so far, any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean old like that. More like a copy from a earlier connection.

Comment: It still isn't clear what you mean.  The SYN packet contains the source and dest port and ip and a random starting sequence number.  If later, the same SYN is used, and the original connection is gone, it is just a new connection.

Comment: [Does TCP/IP prevent packet replays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141128/does-tcp-ip-prevent-packet-replays)

Comment: It does not however do anything about a replayed SYN - and it shouldn't. Two identical SYN packets are compltely valid and fine.